# Select rows with matching columns and all columns match a value for id

Tags: sql, db2

I want to select the distinct id from table 1 that matches the id and gen_id of table 2 only if the Status column results are all 'A' for that id.

TABLE_1

| ID | Gen_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 |
| 1 | 24 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | 28 |
| 3 | 29 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 4 | 32 |
| 4 | 33 |

TABLE_2

| ID | Gen_ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | A |
| 1 | 24 | A |
| 2 | 23 | A |
| 2 | 25 | B |
| 3 | 28 | A |
| 3 | 29 | B |
| 3 | 31 | C |
| 4 | 32 | A |
| 4 | 33 | A |

Desired result:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |

I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM TABLE_1 a
inner join TABLE_2 b on a.id = b.id and a.Gen_ID = b.Gen_ID and b.status ='A'
group by TABLE_1.ID
having SUM(case when b.status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

But that seems to return any record with 'A' as Status.
Actual result:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `b.status ='A'` condition. As it is now `count(*)` counts the 'A' rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `b.status ='A'` from the join :

```
SELECT a.ID, count(1) as totalCount, SUM(case when b.status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) A_count
FROM TABLE_1 a
inner join TABLE_2 b on a.ID = b.ID and a.Gen_ID = b.Gen_ID
group by a.ID
```

will return :

```
ID  TOTALCOUNT  A_COUNT
1   2   2
2   2   1
3   3   1
4   2   2
```

Then a comparison of total count with the count where status = 'A' will give us the expected output:

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM TABLE_1 a
inner join TABLE_2 b on a.ID = b.ID and a.Gen_ID = b.Gen_ID
group by a.ID
having SUM(case when b.status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = count(1)
```

Return :

```
ID
1
4
```